# JS Regex for Multiple DNS servers

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate a form field where a user can input multiple DNS entries. I currently have the regex for validation of a IP address for a single entry but not if a user can add in multiple DNS entries using a "," as the delimiter.

Example (wanting to validate both entries):
192.168.1.1, 198.168.1.2

Regex:
/^((([01]?[0-9]{1,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))[.]){3}(([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))$/

[image: I'm trying to validate the DNS Servers form field]

Comment: Hint: ^regex$ -> ^regex(,\s*regex)*$

Comment: I'm not an expert in regexps, but as far as I know you can hardly implement arbitrary number of comma separated DNS. Even if you can do that, I believe you end up with the monster which nobody would understand how it works. Why don't you just use something like this? `str.split(",").map((str) => str.trim()).every(str => str.match(ipregexp))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not quite sure it's a good idea, as it's quite unreadable, but this should do the job:

```
^(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))(,\s*(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/0uwu2w/1

As others have pointed out, a split on the string and matching individual IP address is probably a better idea.

Even further, even matching a single IP could in turn use split and checking that each component is a number in the 0-255 range.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not trying to validate the whole string, but simply splitting the string on `,` and validating each one individually.

This leaves you with a simpler regex at the cost of a little bit more code. Also, any `[0-9]` in your regex would be simpler if you replaced it with `\d`:

`/^((([01]?\d{1,2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))[.]){3}(([0-1]?\d{1,2})|(2[0-4]\d)|(25[0-5]))$/`

Comment: I quite agree that a split is probably a better option. However your regex is incorrect, it will only match the first three number and following dot, you're missing the last number.